# SCRIPT ERROR: @swerve-basics/client/cl_teleprot.lua:60 bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, fivem

Line with error on it:

```
for zone, data in pairs(Config.zones) do
```

I'm very new to this (I have done python programming and I really need to fix this, if you could help me and walk me through how to fix this would be much appreciated!! The error is in the title of this.

Full Code:

```
ESX = nil local CurrentAction = nil local CurrentActionMsg = '' local HasAlreadyEnteredMarker = false local LastZone = nil

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while ESX == nil do
        TriggerEvent('esx:getSharedObject', function(obj)ESX = obj end)
        Citizen.Wait(0)
    end end)

AddEventHandler('tp:hasEnteredMarker', function(zone)
    if zone == 'MethEnter' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end
    
    if zone == 'MethExit' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end

    if zone == 'WeedEnter' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end         if zone == 'WeedExit' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end

    if zone == 'MoneyWashEnter' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end         if zone == 'MoneyWashExit' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end
    
    if zone == 'CokeEnter' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end
    
    if zone == 'CokeExit' then
        CurrentAction = zone
    end end)

AddEventHandler('tp:hasExitedMarker', function(zone)
    CurrentAction = nil end)

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(3)

        local coords = GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId())
        local isInMarker = false
        local currentZone = nil
        
        for zone, data in pairs(Config.zones) do
            local dist = #(coords - vector3(data.x, data.y, data.z));

            if dist < (data.w) then
                isInMarker = true
                currentZone = zone
                ESX.Game.Teleport(PlayerPedId(), {
                    x = Config.point[zone].x,
                    y = Config.point[zone].y,
                    z = Config.point[zone].z
                })
                CurrentAction = nil
                break
            end

            if data.visible and dist < 10 then
                DrawMarker(
                    data.t,
                    data.x,
                    data.y,
                    data.z,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    0,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    data.w,
                    data.w,
                    data.h,
                    data.color.r,
                    data.color.g,
                    data.color.b,
                    255,
                    false,
                    true,
                    2,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false
                )
            end
        end
        
        if (isInMarker and not HasAlreadyEnteredMarker) or (isInMarker and LastZone ~= currentZone) then
            HasAlreadyEnteredMarker = true
            LastZone = currentZone
            TriggerEvent('tp:hasEnteredMarker', currentZone)
        end
        
        if not isInMarker and HasAlreadyEnteredMarker then
            HasAlreadyEnteredMarker = false
            TriggerEvent('tp:hasExitedMarker', LastZone)
        end
 
    end end)
```

Comment: Based on [this file](https://github.com/gassastsina/FiveM-Scripts/blob/master/resources/%5B.Server%5D/%5Bjobs%5D/esx_ambulancejob/config.lua), maybe `Zones` is uppercase? Where is the Config defined? Does it always contain `zones`?

Comment: It says Config.Zones with all the positions in the config file.

Comment: then change your script to `Config.Zones` (uppercase Z)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have exactly "Config.zones", not "Config.Zones" in your config, if you have it, then you probably didn't type anything in Config.zones or you didn't type it correctly.